# Can you use a location as an activation rule for an iOS application extension?

Tags: ios, info.plist, ios-extensions

I am trying to implement an extension for an iOS app that I would like to present with a location. For example, in the maps app, if you tap the share button, a menu comes up with share options (messages, Facebook twitter) and action options (print, add to favorites). I would like my extension to come up in the action section, and I would like it to be available when there is a location present (like in maps), but there are no predefined info.plist activation rules (like NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount or NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount) for location.

Is there a way to write an NSExtensionActivationRule for action extensions that triggers with a location?